# How to stop the cursor blinking in online LaTeX editors, like ShareLaTeX?

Tags: sharelatex, overleaf, css

Like many, I find it hard to work with a blinking cursor. I've just started using ShareLaTeX, and it's great, but the blinking cursor in the editing panel is genuinely tough to deal with. I found a potential solution on this page:
http://www.jurta.org/en/prog/noblink, which gives the following 'userstyle' code:

```
@-moz-document domain("www.sharelatex.com") {
.ace_cursor {
visibility: visible !important;
}
}
```

Using Google Chrome, I used 'Inspect' to add the above code as a 'New Style Rule', but alas nothing.

Perhaps a different CSS syntax is needed for Chrome? Perhaps there's a simpler fix within ShareLaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid this is the wrong place to ask this question as it has nothing to do with TeX but with web programming and browser settings.

Comment: Hi gernot, could you direct me to the appropriate place to share this question in that case?I thought I'd share it here in case there was LaTeX-specific method of dealing with this issue, despite my attempt using CSS /browser settings.

Comment: I'd try it at the ShareLaTeX site. Choose the Help menu, there is an entry for contacting them.